# How to link tile of a sliding drawer to map activity extended as a fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am beginner in android and trying to link one tile of sliding drawer to map activity extended as fragment. 
I tried it by creating a new Intent and starting it,but it is starting it as new activity and not in the drawer.

Any help is appreciated.

NavDrawer.java

```
public class NavDrawer extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav_drawer);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

                .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                .commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nav_drawer, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nav_drawer, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((NavDrawer) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }

}
```

MapsActivity.java

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

Comment: @Arlind can you please answer my question?

Comment: sorry can you explain more, where do you need to open the map ??

Comment: Id love to help but can you explain more and post more of your layout and MapsActivity code